# zookeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties is throwing "Already in use".how to solve this error in ubuntu?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Vfore starting kafka i tried to start zookeeper server,it is throwing following `java.net.BindException` Exception.

I checked existing processes using :

`netstat -nap|grep 4040 and 8080`

I found no processes running there. can anyone know about this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcAZ5.png)

Comment: This question suffers from bad formatting, low quality and it's not related to spark. Google is your friend, https://askubuntu.com/questions/278448/how-to-know-what-program-is-listening-on-a-given-port

Comment: Thanks for edit..

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to start zookeeper on the default port of 2181. You probably have another zookeeper running. Try running the Java ps command "jps" and kill any other zookeeper process running on the same machine